# Hibernate OGM - MongoDB: How to retrieve data in read-only mode to improve performance

Tags: mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I have a Java application that use Hibernate OGM framework and Mongo database. When I retrieve a lot of data, the application becomes very slow and one of the bottlenecks is Hibernate.

I read that retrive data in a read-only context improve performance a lot. How can I do that?

I had try with method calls like this:

```
entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.READ);
```

or:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, entity)
.setLockMode(LockModeType.READ)
.getResultList();
```

but seems there are not supported.

I can not wait 20 minutes for a few megabytes. Please help!
Every suggestion is appreciated

In my case I have a tree of  one to many associations. The query is on the root, where fetch is set to **LAZY**.
Then i call in a thread the *Hibernate.initialize(proxy)* method on the second level where the recovery is **EAGER**,  to the deeper level.

Comment: Maybe you can describe your use case with more details?

Answer (score 0):

With the entity manager you can use query hints:

```
em.createNativeQuery( query )
  .setHint( "org.hibernate.readOnly", true )
  .getResultList();
```

or you can use the session:

```
em.unwrap( OgmSession.class )
  .createNativeQuery( query )
  .setReadOnly( true )
  .list();
```

Note that if you can add more details about the nature of the problems and if it is an issue in Hibernate OGM, we might create a patch for it.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I've tried both ways, but waiting times are still long.

Maybe I'm wrong to do that? I made query on the highest table in the chain of associations.

Comment: If you can create a test for us to run we can help you more. Your question was about enabling readOnly mode, though, so I think the answer is correct. If your question is too generic for stackoverflow, you can use the hibernate forum: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=31